# Generate a json file dynamically

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, express, jsforce

I need to do a post request using a JSON file. The JSON is currently looking like this:

```
{
        "compositeRequest" : [{
          // Account
          "method" : "POST",
          "url" : "/services/data/v52.0/sobjects/Account",
          "referenceId" : "refAccount",
          "body" : { 
            "Name" : req.body.accName 
          }
        },{
          // Contact
          "method" : "POST",
          "url" : "/services/data/v52.0/sobjects/Contact",
          "referenceId" : "refContact",
          "body" : { 
            "LastName" : req.body.conLastName,
            "AccountId" : "@{refAccount.id}"
          }
        },{
          // Order
          "method" : "POST",
          "url" : "/services/data/v52.0/sobjects/Order",
          "referenceId" : "refOrder",
          "body" : { 
            "AccountId" : "@{refAccount.id}",
            "Pricebook2Id" : PBResult.records[0].Id,
            "EffectiveDate" : date,
            "Status" : "Draft"
          }
        },{
          // OrderItem
          "method" : "POST",
          "url" : "/services/data/v52.0/sobjects/OrderItem",
          "referenceId" : "refOrderItem",
          "body" : { 
            "Product2Id" : req.params.productId,
            "OrderId" : "@{refOrder.id}",
            "Quantity" : req.body.itemQuantity,
            "PricebookEntryId" : entryResult.records[0].Id,
            "UnitPrice" : entryResult.records[0].UnitPrice,
            "blng__BillableUnitPrice__c": entryResult.records[0].UnitPrice,
            "SBQQ__ChargeType__c": prodResult.records[0].SBQQ__ChargeType__c,
            "blng__TaxRule__c": prodResult.records[0].blng__TaxRule__c,
            "blng__BillingRule__c": prodResult.records[0].blng__BillingRule__c,
            "blng__RevenueRecognitionRule__c": prodResult.records[0].blng__RevenueRecognitionRule__c,
            "ServiceDate": date,
            "blng__LastChargeToDate__c": date
          }
        }
      ]
    }
```

I want to generate more OrderItem objects(indicated in the comment) based on the size of an array, how can I do this? I already have the data that I need to add on the body. Is it possible to create a function to create another OrderItem, and place it after the already existing one (it would even be better if I was going to create the first OrderItem from zero).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you give more information? What do you mean by generate more order items based on the size of the array? An example would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add something to an `object`, you have to use

```
Object.assign(myObject, data);
```

If you want to add something to an `array`, you have to use:

```
myArray.push(data);
```

As I don´t really understand the structure of your data construct, I just try to refer to `// OrderItem`, which you marked. In this case it would be something like:

```
let newOrderItem = {
          // OrderItem
          "method" : "POST",
          "url" : "/services/data/v52.0/sobjects/OrderItem",
          "referenceId" : "refOrderItem",
          "body" : { 
            "Product2Id" : req.params.productId,
            "OrderId" : "@{refOrder.id}",
            "Quantity" : req.body.itemQuantity,
            "PricebookEntryId" : entryResult.records[0].Id,
            "UnitPrice" : entryResult.records[0].UnitPrice,
            "blng__BillableUnitPrice__c": entryResult.records[0].UnitPrice,
            "SBQQ__ChargeType__c": prodResult.records[0].SBQQ__ChargeType__c,
            "blng__TaxRule__c": prodResult.records[0].blng__TaxRule__c,
            "blng__BillingRule__c": prodResult.records[0].blng__BillingRule__c,
            "blng__RevenueRecognitionRule__c": prodResult.records[0].blng__RevenueRecognitionRule__c,
            "ServiceDate": date,
            "blng__LastChargeToDate__c": date
          }

yourObject.compositeRequest.push(newOrderItem)
```

Comment: That's exactly it Steven, but if I push it, will it be placed on the right spot? or will it be just placed on the end of the json?

Comment: Yes, if you use `push()` it will be placed at the end. If you need all `OrderItem` at a special position, you need to provide a parent like `orderItems: {}` in your JSON and `apply()`/`push()` your items there. If you specify something like this, I will edit my answer afterwards to explain.